# servlet or filter for Jersey

Tags: rest, servlets, jersey, web.xml

I want to know what is the difference between declaring the "jersey servlet" as Servlet Or as Filter in the web.xml ...

Here is how I called the jersey servlet as Filter in the web.xml :

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey-serlvet</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>ca.tesias.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey-serlvet</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and here is the jersey servlet called as Servlet in the web.xml :

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>ca.tesias.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

What solution should I use !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append a path at the end of base url, you can use **servlets**. However, if you dont want to append a path at the end of base url and just invoke something based on pattern matching, you can use **filters**.

Example

Suppose we have following two resources:

```
@javax.ws.rs.Path("path1")
public class Path1 {

}

@javax.ws.rs.Path("path2")
public class Path2 {

}
```

Now if we have servlet mapping as below:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet_name</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

We can access the resources using following URLs:

```
http://<hostname>:<web_container_port>/<context_root_of_web_application>/rest/path1
http://<hostname>:<web_container_port>/<context_root_of_web_application>/rest/path2
```

On the other hand, if we have filter mapping as below:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter_name</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/path1</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

We can access path1 root resource by visiting the following URL:

```
http://<hostname>:<web_container_port>/<context_root_of_web_application>/path1
```

And in this case, the filter **filter_name** will be invoked

However, if we try to access path2 with following URL:

```
http://<hostname>:<web_container_port>/<context_root_of_web_application>/path1
```

No filter will be invoked in this case.

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_configwebxml_jrsfilters.html